# Failed to create keys in the OLR, rc = 100 on windows server

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac

I am installing Oracle 19c RAC on windows server 2019.
I have 4 servers,

domain controller： pc name = dc

storage: pc name = st

node1: pc name = node1

node2: pc name = node2

I have done all the pre-install checks, and when I install the Grid on node1, i encountered the error below.

> 2023-04-29 21:47:00: Executing cmd:
> C:\software\WINDOWS.X64_193000_grid_home\bin\clscfg -localadd -z  -y
> nodecluster: -p
> CLUSTER_CLASS:Standalone,NODE_LIST:node1~node2~,MULTICAST: 2023-04-29
> 21:47:00: Command output:
>
> > Invalid site guid (-y)
> > clscfg -localadd -z  [-avlookup]
> > -p property1:value1,property2:value2...
> >
> > -avlookup       - Specify if the operation is during clusterware upgrade
> > -z   - Specify the site GUID for this node
> > -p propertylist - list of cluster properties and its value pairs
> >
> > Adds keys in OLR for the HASD.
> > WARNING: Using this tool may corrupt your cluster configuration. Do not
> > use unless you positively know what you are doing.
> >
> > End Command output 2023-04-29 21:47:00: Failed to create keys in the OLR, rc = 100, Message:   Invalid site guid (-y)  clscfg -localadd -z
> >  [-avlookup]                  -p
> > property1:value1,property2:value2...    -avlookup       - Specify if
> > the operation is during clusterware upgrade   -z   -
> > Specify the site GUID for this node   -p propertylist - list of
> > cluster properties and its value pairs   Adds keys in OLR for the
> > HASD. WARNING: Using this tool may corrupt your cluster configuration.
> > Do not          use unless you positively know what you are doing.

my hosts setting

> 10.0.1.66 node1

> 10.0.1.70 node2
>
> 10.0.1.21 nodecluster

> 10.0.1.22 nodecluster

> 10.0.1.23 nodecluster
>
> 10.0.1.76 node1-vip

> 10.0.1.80 node2-vip
>
> 10.0.100.66 node1-pri-ip

> 10.0.100.70 node2-pri-ip

> 10.0.100.99 storage-pri-ip

Anyone can help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug. Please try to patch the GI home during installation.
The problem is that the applyru parameter is not supported on windows.
You can try the following installation sequence:

1. Deinstall the current installation ORACLE_HOME/deinstall/deinstall
2. If asm disk group has already been configured clean the disks. Recreate them if necessary.
3. Reinstall GI but do not configure during installation!
4. Patch the Oracle Home with the latest GI RU.
5. After patching the Oracle Home you can run the configuration.

I don't think the graphical installer supports installation without configuration. So you will have to do a silent installation with a response file.